# Is a singleton object cloneable?

Tags: java, singleton

Can a singleton object be cloned?

I researched and found that one can explicitly override clone() and throw 'CloneNotSupportedException' exception. Since java doesn't enforce it, wouldn't it violate the rule of having a single instance?

Comment: Do you mean *should* instead of *can*?

Comment: a singleton object should NOT be cloneable. If you _must_ have the object be cloneable for some proprietary reason have your clone method do { return this; }

Comment: Singleton is a way of designing object per JVM single object.How can Java standards can enforce anything over there.

Comment: Object clone() method  should not even be used. Cloneable is a clumsy interface.

Comment: If you have two instances, it's not a singleton.You can call it a Singleton and clone it but it won't be a singleton any more.

Comment: @davidxxx clone() is fine for arrays of primitives.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey  do you mean cloning directly an array of primitive ? Indeed, but the array should not have two dimensions otherwise you should perform custom processings. Besides, it is not the classic use case that is cloning an instance of a custom class.

Comment: @davidxxx since it is about the only time I use it, I consider it a classic ;)

Comment: @Peter Lawrey As for many things, it is a point of view :)